# Is a klipa davuk?

Tags: halacha, kashrut-kosher, yoreh-deah

There are many places in the realm of kashrut where something may become forbidden [kedei klipa](http://www.sefaria.org/search?lang=en&q=%22%D7%9B%D7%93%D7%99%20%D7%A7%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%A4%D7%94%22&filters=Halakhah) (just the edge is asur). For those who hold by isur davuk (as isur which is attached to something else - a common example is a not kashered liver inside a chicken), why is a klipa not considered an isur davuk?

Comment: How do you know a Klippah isn't Davuk? Are you talking about a case where they cooked the item whose Klippah was forbidden? Klippah might not be a problem Bedieved in that case anyway, see YD 91:4. I guess I don't really follow what you are asking. Please [edit] to clarify.

Comment: often if something needs kedei klipa if the klipa was not removed and the food item was again cooked in something else it is muter bdieved (for specific applications consult your rav)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This question is in the Rishonim in chapter Gid Hanashe (Chulin Ch. 7, folio 96b in Tosfot).
Klipa is not an issur Davuk.

I quoted here from Rabeinu Yerucham explains that A klipa is a limit of maximal penetration of the Issur. In issur dabuk, there is no such limit. This is the principle in 2 words. 
I remember that there is in Bach something from Raaviah about this<sup>1</sup>.
Here are some words from Rabeinu Yerucham netiv 15 - 3 (copied from the Kovets Shitot Kamai):

> אף על גב דאמרינן חתיכה עצמה נעשית נבלה,
> לא אמרינן כיון דאוסר כדי קליפה או נבלה, אותה קליפה נעשית נבילה
> וחוזרת ואוסרת כל קליפה שאצלה וכן כל קליפה וקליפה
> דלא אמרינן חתיכה עצמה נעשית נבילה ורואין ההיתר כאילו הוא אסור
> אלא כשהאיסור מתפשט במקום שהולך החתיכה אבל בכאן אין האיסור מתפשט אלא כדי קליפה.‏

This is the first explanation, the part of the piece penetrated by the Isur don't prohibit the near part, because the absorbed issur doesn't diffuse deeper.

He give also a second explanation.

> ויש מפרשים
> שאין אומרים חתיכה עצמה נעשית נבילה אלא כשהיא עומדת בפני עצמה
> אבל כאן שהקליפה מחוברת עם הירך אינה נעשית נבלה

There is no Chanan but for a separate entity (an entire piece).
I hope this make sense. See Shach YD 22 SK10 who quotes Rabenu Yerucham.

**EDIT:**

See Chulin 76.2 Tosfot paragraph "Afilu Meresh Ozno", the two explanations are there, **Rabbi Eliezer Mimets** holds that is no CHanan for a no entire piece, **the author of the Tosfot** holds that the first Isur cannot penetrate more than the Kelipa, so, there is no Chanan. But according to **Rabenu Efrayim**, I understand that the both explanations may be wrong. E.g. if there is a Kelipa of Basar Bechalav, this Klipa maybe Nevela according to Rabenu Efrayim and it can prohibit the last part of the piece.

<sup>1</sup>  **Bach YD 92**   **ולא אמרינן חתיכה עצמה נעשה נבלה עד מקום שנבלע עכ"ל ראבי"ה** ונ"ל דהיינו כרא"ם שפי' בפג"ה דלא אמרינן חתיכה עצמה נעשה נבלה בחצי חתיכה עכ"ל מרדכי פכ"ה מדפי' דאין מקצתה שחוץ לרוטב נ"נ ואוסרת את השאר אלמא דמפרש לרש"י הא דתנן אם יש בנ"ט באותה חתיכה דר"ל באותה מקצת חתיכה שחוץ לרוטב יש בה בנ"ט אסור אבל אינו אוסר את השאר ודו"ק:‏

Translation: and it is not said that the piece itself up to the level where it absorbed became Nevela, quotation from the Raaviah.  I think this corresponds to what REM said in the chapter Gid Hanashe that you don't say Chanan for half a piece.  These are the words of the Mordechai in the Kol Habasar chapter. *(Note that the Tosfot in 96b distinguishes between this explanation and the REM explanation)*.